# how to get sum of a column of sub query result column in sql

Tags: php, mysql

this is my query in this sub query gives some output columns and i want sum of total amount committed

```
select x.*,sum(x.AmountCommited)
from
(select
a.TrustMemName,
a.DonorFirstName,
a.AmountCommited,
a.YourCommitmentId,
b.AmountFulfilled,
SUM( CASE WHEN a.DateFulfilled1 between "2017-01-01" and "2017-03-31"
      THEN a.AmountFulfilled          
 END) as quarter1,
SUM( CASE WHEN a.DateFulfilled1 between "2017-04-01" and "2017-06-30"
      THEN a.AmountFulfilled          
 END) as quarter2,
SUM( CASE WHEN a.DateFulfilled1 between "2017-07-01" and "2017-09-30" 
      THEN a.AmountFulfilled          
 END) as quarter3,
SUM( CASE WHEN a.DateFulfilled1 between "2017-10-01" and "2017-12-31" 
      THEN a.AmountFulfilled          
 END) as quarter4
 from
 commitmentcomplete as a left join commitmentsummary as b on 
  a.YourCommitmentId=b.YourCommitmentId
  where a.TrustId=2521
 group by a.YourCommitmentId
 ) as x
```

-------------------------out put------------------

```
  "TrustMemName"        "DonorFirstName"    "AmountCommited"    "YourCommitmentId"  "AmountFulfilled"   "quarter1"          "quarter2"  "quarter3"  "quarter4"
  "nithin"              "xdfcdg"             "4567"                 "171"       "4500"                   "3000"                 "1500"            \N          \N
  "virendra"            "ghgf"              "20000"                 "172" "10000"                               \N       \N     \N       \N
  "virendra"            "ghfgh"            "30000"                  "173"   "15000"                             \N                       "15000"    \N  \N
```

this is sub query result and i want total sum of amountcommitted

Comment: And why doesn't your query work?

Comment: `select
a.TrustMemName,
a.DonorFirstName,
a.AmountCommited,
a.YourCommitmentId,
b.AmountFulfilled,.... GROUP BY a.YourCommitmentId` is wrong SQL read https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: how, it is already executing and giving output

Comment: @Mahantesh It'll give an output but not a good one... You select multiple columns and group by just one

Answer (score 0):

create a view of above sub query then join that view with the above sub query we will get the result